# Istio rating limit with redisquota not taken into account

Tags: kubernetes, istio, rate-limiting

I'm trying to use rate limitings with istio (i've already done it with envoy but the project manager wants me to try it that way). I based my config on the tutorial of istio. I tried a few different things but can't make it work and i don't even know how to debug this. Kiali doesn't give any nice information about quotas, rules,... My goal is to block to max 2 request per XX seconds the traffic to a service. you can find my code here if you want to give a try: https://github.com/hagakure/istio_rating.

first step i did was: istioctl install --set meshConfig.disablePolicyChecks=false --set values.pilot.policy.enabled=true
as said on istio website

then i add some yaml config:

My service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-world-svc
  namespace: rate-limit
spec:
  selector:
    app: hello-world
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

Exposed by Istio:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: hello-world-gateway
  namespace: rate-limit
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
    - port:
        number: 80
        name: http-web
        protocol: HTTP
      hosts:
        - '*'
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: hello-world-vs
  namespace: rate-limit
spec:
  hosts:
    - "*"
  gateways:
    - hello-world-gateway
  http:
    - route:
       - destination:
            port:
              number: 80
            host: hello-world-svc.rate-limit.svc.cluster.local
```

My rate-limiting configuration for istio:

```
apiVersion: "config.istio.io/v1alpha2"
kind: instance
metadata:
  name: requestcount
  namespace: rate-limit
spec:
  compiledTemplate: quota
  params:
    dimensions:
      destination: destination.labels["app"] | destination.service.host | "unknown"
---
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: QuotaSpec
metadata:
  name: quota
  namespace: rate-limit
spec:
  rules:
    - quotas:
        - quota: requestcount.instance.rate-limit
          charge: 1
---
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: QuotaSpecBinding
metadata:
  name: quota-binding
  namespace: rate-limit
spec:
  quotaSpecs:
    - name: quota
      namespace: rate-limit
  services:
    - service: '*'
---
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: handler
metadata:
  name: quotahandler
  namespace: rate-limit
spec:
  compiledAdapter: redisquota
  params:
      redisServerUrl: localhost:6379
      connectionPoolSize: 10
      quotas:
      - name: requestcount.instance.rate-limit
        maxAmount: 2
        validDuration: 30s
---
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: rule
metadata:
  name: quota-rule
  namespace: rate-limit
spec:
  actions:
  - handler: quotahandler.handler.rate-limit
    instances:
    - requestcount.instance.rate-limit
```

But nothing appends, i can curl as much as i want the service, no problem :'(

Comment: What is your istio version?

Comment: 1.6.2 i know it's deprecated but it is still usable no?

Answer (score 0):

> 1.6.2 i know it's deprecated but it is still usable no?

As mentioned in [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/policy-enforcement/rate-limiting/)

> The mixer policy is deprecated in Istio 1.5 and not recommended for production usage.
>
> Consider using [Envoy native rate limiting](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.13.0/intro/arch_overview/other_features/global_rate_limiting) instead of mixer rate limiting. Istio will add support for native rate limiting API through the Istio extensions API.

As far as I know **mixer no longer exist when you install istio**, [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/news/releases/1.5.x/announcing-1.5/upgrade-notes/) says that

> If you depend on specific Mixer features like out of process adapters, you may re-enable Mixer. Mixer will continue receiving bug fixes and security fixes until Istio 1.7.

But I couldn´t find a proper documentation on how to do that.

There is older [github issue](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/21988) about rate limiting when mixer is deprecated.

---

> i've already done it with envoy but the project manager wants me to try it that way

There is a [github issue](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/22068) with envoy filter rate limiting example, which as mentioned in above issue and documentation should be used now instead of deprecated rate limiting from istio documentation. So I would recommend to talk with your project manager about that. This is actually the right way to go.

---

**About the issue** which might occur if you have used older version of istio with mixer or you have enabled it somehow on newer versions.

Take a look at this [github issue](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/19139).

There were some issues with the commands from documentation you mentioned

```
istioctl install --set meshConfig.disablePolicyChecks=false --set values.pilot.policy.enabled=true
```

Instead you should use

```
istioctl install --set values.pilot.policy.enabled=true --set values.global.policyCheckFailOpen=true
```

**OR**

```
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: IstioControlPlane
spec:
  values:
    pilot:
      policy:
        enabled: true
    global:
      policyCheckFailOpen: true
```

---

Hope you find this informations useful.

Comment: I reseted my kubernetes environment  and installed istioctl version 1.4.2 with command line :: istioctl manifest apply --set profile=demo --set values.pilot.policy.enabled=true --set values.global.policyCheckFailOpen=true         But the problem persist

Comment: Could you try with 1.4.3 or higher? The issue I mentioned was fixed in 1.4.3 as  mentioned [here](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/19139#issuecomment-569305080). Additionally check with `kubectl -n istio-system get cm istio -o jsonpath="{@.data.mesh}" | grep disablePolicyChecks` if it actually changed.

Comment: i did try with 1.4.3 still the same and when i look at istio config i get this: disablePolicyChecks: false

# policyCheckFailOpen allows traffic in cases when the mixer policy service cannot be reached.
# Default is false which means the traffic is denied when the client is unable to connect to Mixer.
policyCheckFailOpen: true